# Javascript find the most repetitive character occurrence from the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, hashmap

Let's say we have this string:

```
BBBBAAAABBAAAAAACCCCCBDDDDEEEEEEE,FFF
```

- As you can see, here `B` is occurring 4 times at first but `B` is also present before `DDDD`.
- Similarly, `A` is occurring `4` times at the beginning and later `6` times.

I want the expected output if I am searching `B` it should `4 times` as the max occurrence `B` is 4. However if I am searching `A` then it should return `6` because the most occurrence for `A` is `6`.

Here is my code I tried:

```
function checkRepeatativeString(str) {
    let hashMap = {};
    let seen = new Set();
    let counter = 1;
    let maxValue = 1;
    let isPreviousValueSame = false;
    let isNextValueSame = true;

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        /**
         * is previous value same
         */
        if (str[i] == str[i-1]) {
            isPreviousValueSame = true;
        }
        /**
         * is next value same
         */
        if (str[i] == str[i+1]) {
            isNextValueSame = true;
        }

        if (seen.has(str[i]) && isPreviousValueSame) {
            hashMap[str[i]][0]++;
            hashMap[str[i]][1]++;
            isPreviousValueSame = false;
        } else if(seen.has(str[i]) && !isNextValueSame) {
            maxValue = Math.max(hashMap[str[i]][1], maxValue);
            counter = 0;
            hashMap[str[i]] = [counter, maxValue];
        } else {
            maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, counter);
            seen.add(str[i]);
            hashMap[str[i]] = [counter, maxValue];
            isPreviousValueSame = false;
        }
    }
    return hashMap;
}

let str = "BBBBAAAABBAAAAAACCCCCBDDDDEEEEEEE,FFF";
console.log(checkRepeatativeString(str));
```

This code is working but if you look for `B`, I am getting stuck at the beginning of value.

My program returns out for `B`:

```
B: [ 1, 1 ]
     ^  ^
```

Inside array, `1` is a counter which scans the string and second `1` in array is a max value which should return the output. However my program is returning `1` for B. I am expecting `4` as max value.

Help would be appreciated~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty.

```
function maxConsecutiveCharacters(check, haystack) {
    if(check.length !== 1) return false;
    let result = 0;
    let buffer = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] === check) {
            buffer++;
        }
        else {
            if(buffer > result) {
                result = buffer;
            }
                buffer = 0;
        }
            if(buffer > result) {
                result = buffer;
            }            
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks overly complicated. Consider approaching the problem from a different angle - first split up the string into segments of repeating characters, and group them into an object based on the length of the longest substring for a given character.

```js
const checkRepeatativeString = (str) => {
  const longestCounts = {};
  for (const consecutive of (str.match(/(.)\1*/g) || [])) {
    const char = consecutive[0];
    longestCounts[char] = Math.max(
      longestCounts[char] || 0, // Use the existing value in the object if it exists and is higher
      consecutive.length // Otherwise, use the length of the string iterated over
    );
  }
  return longestCounts;
};

let str = "BBBBAAAABBAAAAAACCCCCBDDDDEEEEEEE,FFF";
console.log(checkRepeatativeString(str));
```

Simpler code often means less surface area for bugs.